# Javascript promises In React-Enzyme test not returning mocked value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, es6-promise, enzyme

I am trying to test a React Component which includes a call to an api library and therefore returns a promise.

The api library looks like this: (utils/api.js)

```
import axios from "axios";
import Q from "q";

export default {
    createTrip(trip) {
        return Q.when(axios.post("/trips/", trip));
    }
}
```

I have mocked it as follows: (utils/__mocks__/api.js)

```
export default {
    createTrip(trip) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let response = {status: 201, data: trip};
            resolve(response)
        })
    }
}
```

The function I am testing is:

```
create() {
    api.createTrip(this.state.trip).then(response => {
        if (response.status === 201) {
            this.setState({trip: {}, errors: []});
            this.props.onTripCreate(response.data);
        } else if (response.status === 400) {
            this.setState({errors: response.data})
        }
    });
}
```

The test is:

```
jest.mock('utils/api.js');
test('succesful trip create calls onTripCreate prop', () => {
    const trip = {'name': faker.random.word()};

    const spy = jest.fn();
    const container = shallow(<TripCreateContainer onTripCreate={spy}/>);

    container.setState({'trip': trip});
    container.instance().create();

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(trip);
    expect(container.state('trip')).toEqual({});
    expect(container.state('errors')).toEqual([]);
});
```

I believe this should work, yet the result of the test is:

```
succesful trip create calls onTripCreate prop

expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expected)

Expected mock function to have been called with:
  [{"name": "copy"}]
But it was not called.

  at Object.test (src/Trips/__tests__/Containers/TripCreateContainer.jsx:74:21)
      at new Promise (<anonymous>)
  at Promise.resolve.then.el (node_modules/p-map/index.js:46:16)
      at <anonymous>
```

I'm not sure how to fix this test, and would be grateful if anyone could help?

Comment: It seems that your `trip` object in your test only has a `name` property. You would need to pass a `response` and `response.status` properties since it's what is resolved from your Promise and that you're are checking its value in your logic

Comment: I have edited the code, but still getting the same error @t3__rry

Comment: Ok could you edit your question as well

Comment: I have already done so, I have changed the mock api.js file @t3__rry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close.

`then` queues a callback for execution.  Callbacks execute when the current synchronous code completes and the event loop grabs whatever is queued next.

The test is running to completion and failing before the callback queued by `then` from within `create()` has a chance to run.

Give the event loop a chance to cycle so the callback has a chance to execute and that should resolve the issue.  That can be done by making your test function asynchronous and awaiting on a resolved promise where you want to pause the test and let any queued callbacks execute:

```
jest.mock('utils/api.js');
test('succesful trip create calls onTripCreate prop', async () => {
    const trip = {'name': faker.random.word()};

    const spy = jest.fn();
    const container = shallow(<TripCreateContainer onTripCreate={spy}/>);

    container.setState({'trip': trip});
    container.instance().create();

    // Pause the synchronous test here and let any queued callbacks execute
    await Promise.resolve();

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(trip);
    expect(container.state('trip')).toEqual({});
    expect(container.state('errors')).toEqual([]);
});
```

Comment: Great thanks, I didn't realise you could await without the instance